# How many arrangements are possible in ABCDEFG such that A is always before B and B is always before C?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many arrangements are possible in ABCDEFG such that A is always before B and B is always before C (when you go from left to right) ?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and where you are stuck. On this forum, you are expected to show your effort when asking for help.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Do you mean immediately before or anywhere before?

Answer (score 0):

*If you want to keep A,B,C in a fixed order you can consider those letters as three equal letters and find number of different arrangements ( permutations) for all 7 letters. Here you get the answer as (7!)/(3!) = 840 . 

But if you need to keep them together in the given order you can take all three as one letter then you get answer as 5! , but I think in your case first approach is much appreciate.*

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the questioner hasn't shown any effort.

Comment: Please read [enforcement of quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).

Comment: @trueblueanil yes that's much better I noted that later , since the questioner is a new contributor I didn't delete my answer.